# How can select dbIndex when I use RedisTemplate in Spring-Data-Redis?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-redis

I'm trying to use Spring-Data-Redis APIs,and want to select dbIndex of redis in RedisTemplate. But I cant find any relevant method in RedisTemplate.java, how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set database index using jedisConnectionFactory bean.
if you are using xml based config, you can set something like this

```
<bean id="jedisConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory" p:host-name="server" p:port="6379">
    <property name="database" value="required index">
<bean/>
```

if you are using java based config, you can set like this inside config bean

```
  @Bean
  public RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    // other configuration

    JedisConnectionFactory connection = new JedisConnectionFactory();
    connection.setDatabase("required db index");

    // other config
    return connection;
  }
```

Comment: Thx for reply @iucid. But use `JedisConnectionFactory` to select dbIndex is so cumbersome,it can't change in my code.For Example, i want connect db 1 in `Class A`, connect db 2 in `Class B`.How can i do this?